# android studio connection reset error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've downloaded a sample project (TimePicker-master) weeks ago from GitHub and since then when ever I try to sync that project i get this error. 
Gradle 'TimePicker-master'project refresh failed 
Error: Connection reset

[image]

i have tried different proxies but it did not work. because i don't know what the problem even is? and i didn't found the reason searching online
now i get the same problem when i try to download intelliJ plugins while I'm using proxies.
what is the problem and how do i solve it ?(be friendly and helpful to beginners)

Comment: Try Kerio or Cisco for sure , Connection Reset is only related to our restrictions on our country , some times government blocks gradle ip some times gradle blocks iranian ip's and there is another possibility maybe your project using a repository which is DOWN for now .

Comment: i'm trying kerio. is this dependency an issue ? classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'

Comment: Check your gradle repos and use a VPN not proxy because most times proxies wont work as well as VPNs

Comment: just did that and same problem

Comment: Open Your Main Build.gradle not the Module Gradle file and check the repositories section :D

Comment: jcenter() is all

Comment: are you sure that you have deleted all proxy settings from gradle local file ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** right now only thing that works at least in IRAN is using v2ray

the problem is not with `gradle`. the problem is that `gradle` cannot connect to the `bintray servers`. `bintray` has blocked some countries from accessing their servers .and because of that `gradle` cannot retrieve `libraries` it needs to build the project and run the application. so what do we do?

**changing the IP address will do the trick.**

now a word of advice to those who are new to android programming or programming in general. do not waste your time on free VPN servers or proxies which has a lot of issues like connection failure, low speed and etc . just buy a premium account from a good service and use that. it'll worth it.

**like this one:**

[image]

another advice is sometimes using protocols like Stunnel and cisco might still cause problems like `connection timeout errors` but **vpn** and **kerio** will always work ok

Answer (score 2):

i solve this problem in this way. be careful it causes with different problems like using proxy, dns connection windows , fire wall block , ....

but i use proxy in file/settings/proxy in android studio and after that i set no proxy.
after that  whenever use kerio vpn or  cisco didnt work.

solution :go to  gradle.propertices and remove every proxy script from there and sync gradle and work fine

Comment: dadash ye vpn khoob vasl kon hame chi hale. kerio va stunnel , baghie protocol ha ham ziad khoob nistan . faghat vpn man az vpnsaz mikharam soraatesh daghighan hamoon sorat internet khodame . ghati ham nadare.

Comment: alireza easazade soltan laanat be in tahrima o filtera. doodesh faghat too cheshme ma mardom mire. :D

Answer (score 1):

Open timepicker-library's gradle file and remove below code from it and try to sync project again.

```
apply plugin: 'bintray-release'

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'
}

publish {
    userOrg = 'erz05'
    groupId = 'com.github.erz05'
    artifactId = 'TimePicker'
    version = '0.1.5'
    description = 'Android Library for TimePicker View'
    website = 'https://github.com/erz05/TimePicker'
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i did it again and changed the gradle version in my dependencies from to 2.2.2 to 2.3.0 and it solved the problem does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

try to do this add  `mavenCentral()` to `gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()   // This repo should have the gradle plugin
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }
```

also check if you are working offline and uncheck it

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my antivirus software was blocking it, disabling antivirus worked for me.

Comment: Also, for me, I was using Kaspersky and "pausing protection" did not work. I had to completely exit Kaspersky in order for Android Studio to connect to the internet? Finally, I was able to install not installed SDK platforms and tools.

Comment: Sometimes, it could be your firewall too, visit https://gradle.org/releases/ and try to download the version your using in gradle-wrapper.properties file, if the site is not opening, contact network support or configure your firewall.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4RfJ.png)

File >> Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Gradle Build >> Android Studio, then tick Enable embedded Maven repository[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4RfJ.png)